# Convert dataframe Pandas using pre-defined columns

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a Pandas DataFrame with multiple rows and columns as follows:

```
      a    b   c   d
0     2    1   3   1
1     2    2   1   1      
2     2    3   6   1    
3     2    4   4   1
```

I want to convert the above DataFrame to matrix based on `column b` as `rows` and `column c` as `column`. Using `crosstab`, I will get:

```
c   1   3   4   6
b
1   0   1   0   0
2   1   0   0   0
3   0   0   0   1
4   0   0   1   0
```

What I want is the column should show from `1-6` including `2` and `5` as below.

```
c   1   2   3   4   5   6
b
1   0   0   1   0   0   0
2   1   0   0   0   0   0
3   0   0   0   0   0   1
4   0   0   0   1   0   0
```

How to obtain the above form using Pandas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html) with minimal and maximal columns:

```
df1 = df.reindex(np.arange(df.columns.min(), df.columns.max() + 1), axis=1, fill_value=0)
print (df1)
   1  2  3  4  5  6
c                  
1  0  0  1  0  0  0
2  1  0  0  0  0  0
3  0  0  0  0  0  1
4  0  0  0  1  0  0
```

Comment: Thanks. It works. If I need to convert to numpy matrix, I just need to use ```.to_numpy()```, right?

Comment: @tfreak - exactly, add `.to_numpy()`